# Как конвертировать большой файл JSON в формат XML python

Tags: python, json, xml

Час добрый

Имеется парсер который собирает с сайта море инфы по каждому объявлению о продаже и сохраняет все в JSON файл. Данный файл по завершению работы имеет вес почти что 10gb, но из-за большого веса не выходит конвертировать его в xml формат

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно разрезать json файл и частями переписать его в xml. Если возможно, то хотя бы с примерным кодом т.к. за вечер поиска не нашел способа это сделать, а все ответы имели характер: "используй такую то библиотеку". Но когда начинал искать как именно пользоваться тем что советовали, то не находил и намека на код для решения проблемы

Сам json имеет около 1750 таких вот элементов, записанных друг за другом по порядку (id - первая строка в каждом списке) :

```
[
                     {
                                          "id": "26177",
                                          "title": "Квартира в стильном и уютном комплексе",
                                          "price": "39 000 €",
                                          "area": "44м2",
                                          "town": "Солнечный Берег",
                                          "complex": "Dawn Park Deluxe",
                                          "year": "2011",
                                          "furniture": "Меблированная",
                                          "distance": "500 метров",
                                          "look": "Бассейн",
                                          "season": "Круглогодичное исп.",
                                          "floors": "0 от 5",
                                          "material": "Кирпич",
                                          "heating": "Электричество",
                                          "parking": "Парковка",
                                          "guard": "есть",
                                          "rooms": [
                                                               "2 комнаты,",
                                                               "1 спальня",
                                                               "1 балкон,",
                                                               "1 ванная"
                                          ],
                                          "elevator": "есть",
                                          "description": "Двухкомнатная квартира в очень стильном и уютном комплексе, построенном во французском стиле, с продуманной инфраструктурой с бассейном, Спа центром, джакузи, тренажерным залом, сауной и хаммамом, собственной прекрасной парковой зоной. При строительстве и в отделке использовались только дорогие качественные материалы. Отличный вариант для круглогодичного проживания. Управляющая компания поддерживает высокий статус обслуживания. Общая площадь квартиры составляет 44,34 м2, расположена на первом (партерном) этаже. Состоит из прихожей, гостиной с обеденной зоной и кухонным уголком, отдельной спальни, санитарного узла с душевой кабиной и террасы. Квартира обставлена мебелью и техникой и готова для проживания.",
                                          "coords": "42.7050475:27.7119821",
                                          "images": [
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/c329c0ab-6914-4cb8-aa7c-ad8700eb8946.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/3a7b2b06-b229-4ed3-a4c2-ad8700eb8950.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/8b51ac61-abde-4126-bc6c-ad8700eb896c.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/abccb1d0-b07e-46d3-86ea-ad8700eb894b.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/bcd3039a-117c-426f-82cb-ad8700eb8983.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/db7d969a-9279-4134-bb52-ad8700eb895e.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/ecae5e2c-5547-4fea-bde1-ad8700eb8983.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/874cbfb1-89ab-498f-94a8-ad8700eb8933.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/c862266a-db42-485d-aeb9-ad8700eb8941.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/9e92c717-fd88-449b-abed-ad8700eb8962.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/b12972e1-21e9-43ff-a287-ad8700eb8921.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/39f143dd-aa66-450e-afd2-ad8700eb8962.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/859c52f2-3a11-49f8-9cf6-ad8700eb8967.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/5b7ef154-47ca-4bdc-baba-ad8700eb8967.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/5a16e579-4899-4eac-9beb-ad8700eb8946.jpg",
                                                               "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/properties/view/26177/photos/0470dc3c-5aef-4902-a2fa-ad8700eb893d.jpg"
                                          ]
                     }
][
                     {
                                          "id": "26177",
...
```

Comment: `][` там везде есть?

Comment: Это не JSON.  В JSON не может быть вот такого `][`.

Comment: но если есть, то это хорошо - можно переписать на итератор